# Why do linear bandits use ridge regression to estimate parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, ridge-regression, multiarmed-bandit

I’m implementing an adaptive experimental design where arms are assigned according to the posterior probability that they are the best arm. I’ve noticed in several articles that people use ridge regression to estimate the coefficient vector and variance-covariance matrix. While I’m used to implementing ridge regression in the presence of many covariates, I’m only including a few covariates along with treatment indicators. Is there a principled reason to use ridge regression in these settings versus OLS?

1. Maria Dimakopoulou et al. "[Estimation Considerations in Contextual Bandits](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.07077.pdf)"
2. Marc Abeille, Alessandro Lazaric. "[Linear Thompson Sampling Revisited](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06534)"

Comment: Can you share citations for 1 or 2 of the articles that you've found using ridge regression in this way? I'm curious and would like to read more.

Comment: Sure! https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.07077.pdf
https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06534